# How to return 404 or 500 or redirect in Next.js 13 custom hook for a page?

Tags: next.js

In Next.js 13 we can fetch data in each component, page or layout. This is great.

Now, we want to reuse our data fetching logic. Thus we have created a custom hook.

We want to reuse the logic of loading blog data across many projects. This is our code:

```
import { useBlogData } from 'blog'

const Blog = async () => {

    const { latestPosts, categories, tags, authors } = await useBlogData()

    return <div>Blog HTML</div>
}
```

As you can see, our `useBlogData` has a complex logic to support different queries for tags, categories, authors, pagination, SEO, etc.

However, we don't know how to return 404 or 500 or how to redirect **from inside** it.

How can we do that?

For example, if a post does not exist, how can we return 404?